# Is there an efficient way of traversing a graph to find connections between two nodes through all combinations of relatiosnhips and nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the datascheme shown in the picture. I want, for instance, to retrieve all "Diseases" connected to "Pathway" through different combinations of edges and nodes in between. If I write:

MATCH (p:Pathway)-[:IS_INVOLVED]-(d:Disease) RETURN DISTINCT d.Name LIMIT 3

The query is executed very fast. If I write:

MATCH (p:Pathway)-[*]-(d:Disease) RETURN DISTINCT d.Name LIMIT 3

It takes forever to finish. My suspicion is that it traverses to the Compound node at the beginning and checks if there is a connection to the node Disease. Since there is a fairly large number of Compound nodes, the execution time is extremely large. Is there a way to hint the engine to take a specific approach when traversing? Maybe influencing the query execution plan in some way?

My dataset is expected to increase so it

[Data Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGfO1.png)

The only way of retrieving some results without an excessive wait time is by limiting the edge depth constraint to 1 or 2 (i.e. -[*..2]-). I am hoping to be able to retrieve results connected by a maximum of 6-edge paths (i.e. -[*..6]- or -[*]-).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use APOC free plugin, which is much faster. For example [`apoc.path.subgraphNodes`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/expand-subgraph-nodes/):

```
MATCH (p:Pathway)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(p, {
    labelFilter: ">Disease",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 6
})
YIELD node
RETURN DISTINCT node.name;
```

To find all `Disease` which are connected to a `Pathway` node in up to 6 moves. Note that this query will consider any `p:Pathway` and not a specific node `p`. You can change the `MATCH` to find a specific origin. You can also define specific labels, relationships and directions to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid performance issues, you could have specified the *directionality* of the relationship:

```
MATCH (p:Pathway)-[*]->(d:Disease)
RETURN DISTINCT d.Name
LIMIT 3
```

Your data model has only a single relationship type (`IS_INVOLVED`) between the `Pathway` and `Disease` nodes, and that relationship is directed from `Pathway` to `Disease`. If your `MATCH` clause does not specify the directionality, then your unlimited variable-length query would follow other relationship types from `Pathway` (in the reverse direction) and keep going (in any direction) -- so you could be searching a large portion of the entire graph over and over again in the worst case.

And, since your data model has no outgoing relationships from the `Disease` node, it really makes no sense for the directional query to also be a variable-length query as well -- since all matching paths would be of length 1.

So, you might as well just stay with your first query.